# getWinSize() in COCOS2DX returns apparently incorrect resolution

Tags: ios, iphone, cocos2d-x

In `AppDelegte` when I call `Director::getInstance()->getWinSize()`, it gives me the same resolution (960*640) for every screen. I've tested on iPad Retina, iPhone Retina and iPad.

I'm using ccbis and my game is in landscape.

```
bool AppDelegate::applicationDidFinishLaunching()
{


    // initialize director
    auto director = Director::getInstance();
    auto glview = director->getOpenGLView();

   if(!glview) {
      glview = GLView::create("My Game");
      director->setOpenGLView(glview);
    }

    Size winSize = Director::getInstance()->getWinSize();
```

Comment: i) What version of cocos2dx you are using. ii) show the code where you have setup your glView.

Comment: you should search for _setDesignResolution_ method call in your sources and take a look at multi resolution support in cocos2d-x here http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/Multi_resolution_support

Comment: Shoaib I'm using cocos2d-x-3.1.1. That's what I'm doing

Comment: I've followed the same link musikov

Comment: @BilalHassan try using Size frameSize = Director::getInstance()->getOpenGLView()->getFrameSize();

Comment: What about `CCEGLView::sharedOpenGLView()->getVisibleSize()`?

Comment: Thank you @Guy Kogus  but nothing worked

Comment: @musikov it gives same size as getWinSize()

Comment: what design resolution have you set for resources?